# cannot see the output

Tags: python, lambda

```
items = [("A",5,6),("A",4,5),("A",3,8),("B",6,9),("B",7,4),("C",9,2)]
q2= filter(lambda x: x.count("A"),items)
q4= map(lambda x: x[1], items)
list(q4)
print("Q2 = {}".format(q2))
print("Q4 = {}".format(q4))
```

I cannot understand why the out put dos not show ?!
I try to count how many A in the list and print the 2nd items
Q2 = 
Q4 =

Comment: please clarify your question. What is your expected output?

Comment: `filter` expects the lambda to return `True` or `False`, but it will return `1` or `0` (in this example).

Comment: I want to count How many A in My list the output should show 3

Comment: If you are using python 2.x, To count A, do: `print map(lambda x: x[0],items).count('A')`. If you are using python 3.x , you should get a map object. Make it a list first.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering the `items` correctly but then you should apply your next step on `q2` because filter does not change `items`. It returns the result and you are assigning it to `q4`. So:

```
items = [("A",5,6),("A",4,5),("A",3,8),("B",6,9),("B",7,4),("C",9,2)]
q2= filter(lambda x: x.count("A"),items)
q4= map(lambda x: x[1], q2)
list(q4)
print("Q2 = {}".format(q2))
print("Q4 = {}".format(q4))
```

Comment: I face the same problem in q4 it also ?!

Comment: output of this code is: `Q4 = [5, 4, 3]` isn't is what you want? if it isn't please clarify your question and elaborate about your expected output.

Comment: the output I want as follow Q2= 3 , Q4 = [5,4,3,6,7,9] sorry I am beginner in python

Comment: I don't get it. You original code output is `Q4 = [5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 9]` and you are saying your expected output is that too. So what is the problem?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 shouldn't the penultimate line be ...format(len(q2)) to get what the OP wanted?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

```
print map(lambda x: x[0],items).count('A')
```

Or,

```
print [i[0] for i in items if i[0]=='A']
```

For your second question:

```
print map(lambda x:x[1],items)
```

Comment: thank you. I have one more question. What are the 3rd values for items that have a 2nd value greater than 4. the code of this

Comment: pretty straightforward, `[i[2] for i in items if i[1]>4]`